# Lua script for g502 hero , loop until key press again

Tags: lua, logitech-gaming-software

I need Lua script start when I press M4 button on mouse press keys but I need this in loop until I press M4 again.

**-- NOT HOLD - PRESS AGAIN --**

here is my code;

```
local M4_pressed = false

function OnEvent(event, arg)
    if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 4 then
        M4_pressed = not M4_pressed
        while M4_pressed do
            PressKey("2")
            Sleep(math.random(60, 70))
            ReleaseKey("2")
            Sleep(math.random(60, 70))
        end
    end
end
```

this is my code but its not stopping on press again.

---

```
M4_pressed = not M4_pressed 
/*this means 
    if(M4_pressed = true){M4_pressed = false)}
    if(M4_pressed = false){M4_pressed = true)}
*/
```

Comment: And your problem is?

Comment: @Marc i added my code and it doesn't stop

Comment: @Marc i edit question again can you help me ?

Comment: You need to check in your while loop if the button was pressed again. Once you enter the loop and it runs forever nothing else outside of the loop is executed.

Answer (score 0):

You should write a function to poll the MB4 status while sleeping.
Transition of `IsMouseButtonPressed(4)` from `false` to `true` means MB4 is pressed for the second time.

```
local MB4_pressed, second_MB4_press

local function InterruptableSleep(ms)
   local tm_stop = GetRunningTime() + ms
   while not second_MB4_press and GetRunningTime() < tm_stop do
      Sleep(10)
      local MB4 = IsMouseButtonPressed(4)
      MB4_pressed, second_MB4_press = MB4, MB4 and not MB4_pressed
   end
end

function OnEvent(event, arg)
   --OutputLogMessage("event = %s, arg = %s\n", event, tostring(arg))
   if event == "MOUSE_BUTTON_PRESSED" and arg == 4 then
      MB4_pressed = not MB4_pressed
      if MB4_pressed then
         second_MB4_press = false
         repeat
            PressKey("2")
            InterruptableSleep(math.random(40, 90))
            ReleaseKey("2")
            InterruptableSleep(math.random(40, 90))
         until second_MB4_press
      end
   end
end
```

Comment: this is not stoping on press again

Comment: @MertMalaves - Make sure you have standard action "Back" assigned to physical MB4 in GHub GUI (on the big picture of mouse)

Comment: Just checked my script on GHub - it works.